# Playing Sounds in Next.js 13 + TypeScript

Tags: typescript, audio, next.js

I'm trying to play a sound whenever a user gets an answer right or wrong, but I'm having a hard time doing that in Next.js. A lot of the packages out there seem like they aren't compatible.

I've tried using packages like use-sound and Audio().play(), but still didn't get it to work.

Heres the code I'm working with:

```
if (inputValue.toLowerCase() == "yes") {
  // correctSound.play();
  setIsSuccess(true);
  setInputValue("");
  props.setUserWords([inputValue.toLowerCase(), ...props.userWords]);
} else {
  // errorSound.play();
  setEffect(true);
  setIsFailed(true);
}
if (inputRef.current != null) {
  inputRef.current.focus();
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.